# Selecting element within element of same type using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a nested html structure like this:

```
<ul class="root">
    <li>Foo 1 <label class="bar-class">bar</label>
         <ul>
            <li>Foo 2 <label class="bar-class">bar</label>

            </li>

            <li>Foo 3 <label class="bar-class">bar</label>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And so on, it is a site map so the nesting can be as deep as you like.

I am trying to show and hide the `bar label` on hover of the `li element`.

With code like this:

```
 $('.root li').live({
                mouseenter:
                       function () {
                           $(this).find('>.bar-class').show('slow');
                       },
                mouseleave:
                       function () {
                           $(this).find('>.bar-class').hide('fast');
                       }
            });
```

The problem is, that every `li` parent of the current also shows its `bar`, how do I select it so that ONLY the current item's bar gets selected?

I've tried variations but just not cracked it yet.

Thanks.

Edit 1: Fixed html tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return `false` from the callback function to stop further propagation of the event up the DOM tree.

And also change to using `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
$('.bar-class').hide();

$('.root li').live({
  mouseover:
    function () { $(this).find('>.bar-class').show('slow'); return false; },
  mouseout:
    function () { $(this).find('>.bar-class').hide('fast'); return false; }
});​
```

At this point I would like to encourage you to convert from using `live` to using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), because `live` is deprecated.

In this case, the code becomes:

```
$('.root').on('mouseover mouseout', 'li', function () {
  $(this).children('.bar-class').stop(true, true).fadeToggle('slow');
  return false;
});​
```

Reference thanks to [Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697154/yoshi): http://jsfiddle.net/6FzWU/2/

Comment: this is almost there, thanks, odd behaviour though, when i move from the parent li to the child li, the parent doesnt hide...? this works much better though other wise.

Comment: use `mouseover`, `mouseout` instead of `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`.

Comment: This is the final working version, http://jsfiddle.net/dNxsv/1/ using input from @ronalchn and yoshi solutions

Comment: thx, I was going to fix it by creating another span container for "Foo 1 bar", but the `mouseover`,`mouseout` solution is more elegant. Also, changing to `on()`. Toggle also very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.preventDefault()`, and also `.live` is deprecated, use `.on`

```
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.bar-class').show('slow');
  },

  mouseleave: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.bar-class').hide('fast');
  }
}, '.root li');
```

Comment: you don't need any e.preventDefault(), there is any postback on that hovering.

Comment: FYI, what you currently have is not a direct replacement for his use of `live()`; `$(document).on({ /* event map */ }, '.root li')` would be though.

Comment: @AndreaTurri: You need the `e.preventDefault()` (or at least `return false;` there to stop the event handler propagating to the ancestors which match the selector, so "Stop downvoting before check it on JsFiddle plz! "